# Pivot table from sql to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have following two tables `Events` and `EventType`

I need to do something in order to present my columns EventType names (Direct beneficiaries, Capacity Development, Reach, Online Reach) and Total column which is the sum of all these columns (in particular row):

[image: Result]

My sql tables are structered as it is on this image:
[image: SQL tables]

*Note: If there no eventTypeId in table Events, then, don't show in pivot table that column.

Those numbers presents TotalAttendants for all events that held up in january, february, etc.

If there no cumulative events in March, that month should be empty (March will be here also, but instead of numbers, just empty spaces).

I tried following linq expression:

```
var response = _context.Events
                    .Where(x => query.ProjectId.HasValue ? x.ProjectId.Equals(query.ProjectId) : true)
                    .Where(x => x.Date.Year.Equals(query.Year))
                    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                    .GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Date.Year, Month = x.Date.Month })
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        DirectBeneficiaries = x.Where(m => m.EventTypeId == Domain.Enums.EventType.DirectBeneficiaries)
                            .Select(u => new EventTotal
                            {
                                Month = u.Date.Month.ToString("MMMM"),
                                FemaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.FemaleAttendants),
                                MaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.MaleAttendants),
                                TotalAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.TotalAttendants)
                            }),
                        CapacityDevelopment = x.Where(m => m.EventTypeId == Domain.Enums.EventType.CapacityDevelopment)
                            .Select(u => new EventTotal
                            {
                                Month = u.Date.Month.ToString("MMMM"),
                                FemaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.FemaleAttendants),
                                MaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.MaleAttendants),
                                TotalAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.TotalAttendants)
                            }),
                        Reach = x.Where(m => m.EventTypeId == Domain.Enums.EventType.Reach)
                            .Select(u => new EventTotal
                            {
                                Month = u.Date.Month.ToString("MMMM"),
                                FemaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.FemaleAttendants),
                                MaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.MaleAttendants),
                                TotalAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.TotalAttendants)
                            }),
                        OnlineReach = x.Where(m => m.EventTypeId == Domain.Enums.EventType.OnlineReach)
                            .Select(u => new EventTotal
                            {
                                Month = u.Date.Month.ToString("MMMM"),
                                FemaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.FemaleAttendants),
                                MaleAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.MaleAttendants),
                                TotalAttendants = x.Sum(i => i.TotalAttendants)
                            })
                    });
```

but Im getting anonymous type at the end, and I dont know how to cast to my `EventTotal` model:

```
    public class EventTotal
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int? FemaleAttendants { get; set; }
        public int? MaleAttendants { get; set; }
        public int? TotalAttendants { get; set; }
    }
```

My questions is: how to convert it to a specific model?

**Update #1:**

I tried with this code but I have an db exception.

```
"Column 'Events.TotalAttendants' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.Date\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.Date\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.Date\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound.\r\nThe multi-part identifier \"e.EventTypeId\" could not be bound."
```

this is the code

```
var eligibleEvents = _context.Events
        .Where(x => query.ProjectId.HasValue ? x.ProjectId.Equals(query.ProjectId) : true)
        .Where(x => x.Date.Year.Equals(query.Year))
        .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
        .GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Date.Year, Month = x.Date.Month, EventType = (int)x.EventTypeId });

var eventTotals = eligibleEvents.GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Key.Year, Month = x.Key.Month },

    (yearMonthCombination, eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination) => new EventTotal
    {
        Month = yearMonthCombination.Month,
        CapacityDevelopment = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination.Where(u => u.Key.EventType == (int)Domain.Enums.EventType.CapacityDevelopment).Select(u => u.Sum(s => s.TotalAttendants)).Sum(),
        DirectBeneficiaries = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination.Where(u => u.Key.EventType == (int)Domain.Enums.EventType.DirectBeneficiaries).Select(u => u.Sum(s => s.TotalAttendants)).Sum(),
        OnlineReach = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination.Where(u => u.Key.EventType == (int)Domain.Enums.EventType.OnlineReach).Select(u => u.Sum(s => s.TotalAttendants)).Sum(),
        Reach = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination.Where(u => u.Key.EventType == (int)Domain.Enums.EventType.Reach).Select(u => u.Sum(s => s.TotalAttendants)).Sum(),
        Total = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination.Select(u => u.Sum(s => s.TotalAttendants)).Sum(),
        TotalAttendants = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination.Select(u => u.Sum(s => s.TotalAttendants)).Sum()                        
    }).ToList();

return eventTotals;
```

Comment: I have a question. Why not a [mre]? Why not creating 2 list with 2-3 items as input. And a 3rd class, and list for the expected result. The phone squetch is cool and all. But nothing is revelant to the question.. 2 class with 2 properties (id/ pk/ bugus field) and 1 class for the result. and 6 lines of array initialization. You will then easly scale it up to your object complexity by renaming properties.

Comment: You should not expect us to run OCR in order to get column name, and deduct property name from it.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will re-edit :)

Comment: Before doing that, please look for other questions on LINQ + pivot. This is a recurring topic.

Comment: @GertArnold I searched for it, and I think I found the solution, but I have doubts regarding packing a response to my object, Also, I'm not sure that my model `EventTotal` is what I need to show on the front. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *I dont know how to cast to my EventTotal model* -- so what is the output you're trying to pass to the UI? Anyway, I think sooner or later you'll arrive at the same conclusion as many other developers: use a stored procedure that carries out the pivoting and read the data with Dapper.

Answer (score 1):

So from your sequence of `Events`, you want to extract a sequence of `EventTotals`: one EventTotal per group of Events that are from the same [Year, Month].

- Well, not from all Events, only those that are not Deleted
- And from those that were not deleted, you only want the ones that match the ProjectId and the Year

First of all: we can optimize the start of your query: put everything in one `Where`:

```
var eligibleEvents = dbContext.Events
    .Where(event => !event.IsDeleted
        && event.Date.Year == query.Year)
        && (!query.ProjectId.HasValue || query.ProjectId == event.ProjectId)
```

In words: from all Events, keep only those events that are not deleted yet, and that have a `Date.Year` that equals `query.Year`. Depending on whether `query.ProjectId` is null or not, you keep all these events, or you keep only those events with a value for `ProjectId` that equals `query.ProjectId`

Consider to simplify the OR as follows:

```
(query.ProjectId == null) || (query.ProjectId == event.ProjectId)
```

Now from all remaining `Events`, we make groups of Events. All Events that have the same [Year, Month] combination will be in one group. From every Group we make exactly one `EventTotal`.

If you use GroupBy, and you want to create one object from every Group, like we do, consider to use the [overload of GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__3_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2___)

Continuing the LINQ:

```
var eventTotals = eligibleEvents.GroupBy(event => new
{
    Year = event.Date.Year,
    Month = event.Date.Month,
},

// parameter resultSelector: from every [Year, Month] combination,
// and all eligible events that have these values of Year / Month,
// make one new EventTotal:
(yearMonthCombination, eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination) => new EventTotal
{
    Month = yearMonthCombination.Month,

    // Count the zero or more FemaleAttendants:
    FemaleAttendants = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination
        .Select(event => event.FemaleAttendants)
        .Sum(),

    // Count the zero or more MaleAttendants:
    MaleAttendants = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination
        .Select(event => event.MaleAttendants)
        .Sum(),

    TotalAttendants = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination
        .Select(event => event.TotalAttendants)
        .Sum(),
}
```

If `TotalAttendants`  is always the sum of the FemaleAttendants and MaleAttendants, why is it a separate column? Consider to change the property:

```
public int TotalAttendants => this.FemaleAttendants + this.MaleAttendants;
```

By the way, why are your attendants nullable? is there a difference between zero attendants and null attendants? If not, consider to remove the nullable, you only make life more difficult for you.

If you really want if nullable, when should zero attendants be converted to null? Alas you forgot to define this.

### This won't fill your table

You specifically asked for `EventTotals`. I don't see how this would help you to fill the table.

If you want a row with [Month, DirectBenificaries, CapacityDevelopment, ...], I would go for a different resultSelector:

```
(yearMonthCombination, eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination) => new
{
    Month = yearMonthCombination.Month,

    DirectBenificiaries = eventsWithThisYearMonthCombination
        .Where(event => event.EventTypeId == dbContext.EventTypes
                        .Where(eventType => eventType.Name == "DirectBenificiaries")
        .Select(event => ...)
        .Sum(),
```

Alas, you didn't tell us what property you use to make up the DirectBenificiaries of Jan 2020. Is it the total number of events with type DirectBenificiaries? Or is if the total number of Attendants in January 2020 with DirectBenificiaries?

The other columns are similar.

Comment: can you please update your code and nice format it, because, I'm getting errors when I just copy paste it? thanks

Comment: please see my update#1 code, I just slightly changed some stuff. I need TotalAttendants per each eventtypeId though the months/years.